# Need a query to change a geometry column value to a new one based on the old one

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have a GeoDjango database table that looks like this:

```
# \d spirits_spirit
        Table "public.myapp_mymodel"
  Column  |           Type        |    Modifiers                          
----------+-----------------------+------------------
 id       | integer               | not null default nextval('spirits_spirit_id_seq'::regclass)
 activity | integer               | not null
 location | geography(Point,4326) |
```

There are more columns in there of course, but these are the only two that are likely to be relevant.  I should also point out that this table has potential to be Very Large, in the area of hundreds of thousands or even millions of rows.

Now, what I want to do, is change the location of all of objects that match `activity = 3` or whatever.  The location needs to be `n` metres from the current location, where `n` is a random number between say, 10 and 100.

Effectively I want my objects to *move* and I'd like to do it in a single `UPDATE` query, rather than looping over everything in Python... unless someone thinks that this is a Bad Idea.

The problem for me is that I don't know how to do:

```
UPDATE
  myapp_mymodel
SET
  location.x = location + 0.5,
  location.y = location + 0.2
WHERE
  activity = 3;
```

...or whatever without looping over everything, creating an instance of the object, doing the adjustments in Python and then doing a `.save()`.  My grasp of how PostGIS works is currently limited to how GeoDjango hides everything through it's ORM, so I'm asking here:

Is this possible?  Is it even a Good Idea?  Is it actually better to do this all in a Python loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to do updates of data at the database level, in my opinion, than bringing it to the client -- it is one of the things databases are optimized to do. I am not sure how you are defining the random amount to move x and y by, but one thing you could use is [ST_Translate](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Translate.html) which will move a geometry by an amount in the x and y directions. So in your case, for example,

```
UPDATE
  myapp_mymodel
SET
  location = ST_Transform(ST_Translate(ST_Transform(location::geometry,
               3857), random()*10, random()*10) ,4326)
WHERE
  activity = 3;
```

where the x and y are being moved by some number between 0 and 10 and the geometry is updated in place. This looks messier than it is. Basically, there are four steps.

1. You cast the location to geometry, as the ST_Translate function does not work with geography.
2. Use ST_Transform to convert your degrees of lat/lon (EPSG:4326) to something in meters, in this case, Spherical Mercator (EPSG:3857). This is a good choice because it is a projection that covers the whole globe.
3. Use ST_Translate to translate by some meters in x/y direction.
4. Use ST_Transform again to go back to lat/lon, (EPSG:4326), again.

**Caveat**. Spherical Mercator (3857) was developed by Google to cover the whole globe in projected meters. It makes the mathematics of projections very tractable (as it assumes as spherical earth), but does suffer from scale/distance distortion, the further you get from the equator. If you want extremely accurate movements in meters, you will need to use a different coordinate system.

**Note**: EPSG stands for European Petroleum Survey Group and is the organization that manages spatial reference systems, such as 4326 or 3857. These are known as SRID, spatial reference ID, within Postgis.

**Note 2**. You can use ST_Translate in degrees too, but then your movement in the x and y direction will need to be expressed in degrees. This will avoid the double ST_Transform, but mean adding another calculation to convert meters to degrees.

I have done updates of this nature in Postgres/Postgis on millions of rows without problem. The only caveat is that you have enough space to store the changes, as an update is a single transaction, and will need to be rolled back if something goes wrong. Depending on the range of values in the activity field, it is probably worth while having an index on activity too (explain is your friend there).

Comment: It looks good, but now I'm getting `function st_translate(geography, double precision, double precision) does not exist` -- I assume I need to define something first?  This database was definitely created with PostGIS support and the geography columns have been doing what you'd expect so far, so I figure I must be missing something else?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, you defined your location as a geography. You can cast the geography to a geometry and it will work.

Comment: Actually, no, because now the translate is happening in degrees not meters. This can be fixed, but, first, do you definitely need to have your data as a geography type. See this for some discussion on the difference: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26082/what-is-the-difference-between-geometric-and-geographic-columns. There is a function, ST_Transfrom, which you can use to convert from degrees to something projected in meters in order to move by a number of meters in x/y direction, which could work, but you need to explain a bit about the spread of your data, geom/geog types, etc, first

Comment: If I'm understanding that URL correctly, then I think I still need `geography` since these points are scattered all over the globe and I'm regularly doing GeoDjango queries to get "all objects located within `n` metres of lat,lng".  Objects are dealt with internally in terms of lat/lng and I don't really make use of metres save for the case mentioned here.  Is this likely to be a problem that makes it worthwhile using `geometry`?

Comment: Not necessarily. I will update my answer to take that into account.

Comment: You accepted before I update my answer :D It is much messier now, but allows you to translate in meters, while keeping everything in geography.

Comment: I think I accepted it because I thought I understood it, but now that you've changed it, it's a little confusing.  Could you maybe update your answer with an explanation as to why you're using `ST_TRANSFORM` twice and why you needed those two numbers: `3857` and `4326`?  Just to be clear, your answer works, but I'm just trying to understand *why* it works.

Comment: @DanielQuinn. I have updated my answer. I hope it is clearer, if not let me know.